# (Python) psycopg2 installation

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2

I have a fairly light amount of experience with Python and got stuck on what should be a pretty simple issue.  I am using Jupyter Notebook on a Mac.

I wanted to install psycopg2 in Python so I typed in

```
import psycopg2 as pg2
```

But, I got the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-1-32fa0c891bdd> in <module>
 ----> 1 import psycopg2 as pg2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I then went over to the terminal and typed in:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

which resulted in another error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the 
directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path 
with the
option:
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
```

I'm not sure how to go about using this information in the error message.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Also follow up question:

a.) Why would I need to use pip install modulename in the terminal when I don't have to do that with either pandas or numpy?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For "A", some python distributions such as conda come pre-packaged with some commonly used external modules. The default python distribution does not come with `pandas` or `numpy` and needs to be pip installed as well.

Comment: `pg_config` that your system is missing is part of postgres. You need to install postgres on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try installing psycopg2-binary as you probaly do not have all the C library dependencies installed on your computer.
`pip install psycopg2-binary`