# Why is psycopg2 failing to install correctly on Mac OS Catalina Version 10.15.3

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, psycopg2

**This is the error message I get**:

```
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/macbookpro/Documents/brck/subscription_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/b1/wfq4dcls5dbdjq9zl49z_6t40000gp/T/pip-install-6btertcf/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/b1/wfq4dcls5dbdjq9zl49z_6t40000gp/T/pip-install-6btertcf/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/b1/wfq4dcls5dbdjq9zl49z_6t40000gp/T/pip-wheel-zfvo13ls
       cwd: /private/var/folders/b1/wfq4dcls5dbdjq9zl49z_6t40000gp/T/pip-install-6btertcf/psycopg2/
```

If anyone has a solution please reach out

Comment: Show us the real error message. It should be earlier in the output.

Comment: @KlausD. that is the first output

Comment: Yes it does @MauriceMeyer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I answered this by installing `psycopg2-binary` instead of `psycopg2`
I referred to this issue: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/674
And this [(Python) psycopg2 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242390/python-psycopg2-installation)